# How to use Rstudio relative paths

Tags: r, path, rstudio

How can I use relative paths in a [RStudio project](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) environment?

For example, to access a file, I use the whole path:

```
# My RStudio project working directory:

getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/MaurizioLocale/OneDrive/Data_Science/10_Capstone_project/
     CP_Natural_Language/MY_FILE.txt"
```

But it is really long.

I am trying to use paths *relative* to the working environment. I tried something conceptually similar to:

```
"~/MY_FILE.txt"
```

where `~` represents the working environment. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Would [projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) help you with your `wd` ?

Comment: I would like to use shorter paths while working inside a project. Do you think  I should make the question more straightforward?

Comment: All paths in R can be relative to the working directory. Working directory is set by Rstudio project automagically. For instance, I keep all data inside `/data` folder and when I load it, I use `read.table("./data/file.txt"...)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thanks for make me the problem more straightforward. If you post an answer, I will close the question.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, is there any harm in skipping the leading `./`- e.g.: `read.table("data/file.txt")`?

Comment: @Valentin it appears to be working on Windows.

Comment: Beware. For code written in .Rmd files the working directory is the directory in which said .Rmd file is saved, even if it does not agree with the result of `getwd()`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could change the working directory. Get the address in the beginning `getwd()`, replace it by your project folder with `setwd()`. Then, when accessing a file just use `read.table("./folder/file.R")`.

Comment: The dot `.` means it is the working directory set by the command `setwd()`.

Answer (score 29):

The so-called [here](https://github.com/r-lib/here) package is really useful for avoiding absolute paths in (as well as outside of) RStudio. Suppose you have an RStudio project and want to access the file `/data/file.txt`. This would be done as follows. This way, you don't have to mess around with `getwd()`, just work relative to your project root using `here()`.

```r
library(here)
#> here() starts at C:/test/someproject
here("data", "file.txt")
#> "C:/test/someproject/data/file.txt"
readLines(here("data", "file.txt"))
#> "The here package is awesome!"
```

How here figures out where your project root is is described in `?here` and also in the ["Ode to the here package"](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) by Jenny Bryan.